# Count total rows return by query result in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the Total of  rows return by  query result in SQL Server with the following query:

```
select a._PROCESS_INST_NO,a._ISSUER,a._ISSUE_DATE,d._PROCESS_CONTENTS,
            d._OPT_DIVISION,b._GOODS_CD,b._GOODS_NAME,b._QTY,
            a._Order_No,c._GOODS_CD,c._GOODS_NAME,a._NOTE,
            ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a._PROCESS_INST_NO ORDER BY d._PROCESS_CONTENTS) )Proc_Step_No
            --,() as Total_Rows
 from [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PH] a
inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PM] b
on b._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] c
on c._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PN] d
on d._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
where a._PROCESS_INST_NO='609390'
```

,**() as Total_Rows** is the statement that I am waiting for.
I cannot use count(*) in this case. Please help
[image]

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@@RowCount`

```
select a._PROCESS_INST_NO,a._ISSUER,a._ISSUE_DATE,d._PROCESS_CONTENTS,
            d._OPT_DIVISION,b._GOODS_CD,b._GOODS_NAME,b._QTY,
            a._Order_No,c._GOODS_CD,c._GOODS_NAME,a._NOTE,
            ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a._PROCESS_INST_NO ORDER BY d._PROCESS_CONTENTS) )Proc_Step_No
           ,@@rowCount as Total_Rows
 from [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PH] a
inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PM] b
on b._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] c
on c._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PN] d
on d._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
where a._PROCESS_INST_NO='609390'
```

**UPDATE** `@@Rowcount` will not work if you have any query before this query. Try below:

```
;with testCTE as 
(
select a._PROCESS_INST_NO,a._ISSUER,a._ISSUE_DATE,d._PROCESS_CONTENTS,
            d._OPT_DIVISION,b._GOODS_CD,b._GOODS_NAME,b._QTY,
            a._Order_No,c._GOODS_CD,c._GOODS_NAME,a._NOTE,
            ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a._PROCESS_INST_NO ORDER BY d._PROCESS_CONTENTS) )Proc_Step_No

 from [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PH] a
inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PM] b
on b._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] c
on c._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PN] d
on d._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
where a._PROCESS_INST_NO='609390'
)

select * 
, (select count(*) from testCTE) as Total_Rows
from testCTE
```

You can also use `COUNT(*) OVER ()`

```
select a._PROCESS_INST_NO,a._ISSUER,a._ISSUE_DATE,d._PROCESS_CONTENTS,
                d._OPT_DIVISION,b._GOODS_CD,b._GOODS_NAME,b._QTY,
                a._Order_No,c._GOODS_CD,c._GOODS_NAME,a._NOTE,
                ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a._PROCESS_INST_NO ORDER BY d._PROCESS_CONTENTS) )Proc_Step_No
               ,COUNT(*) OVER () as Total_Rows
     from [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PH] a
    inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PM] b
    on b._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
    inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] c
    on c._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
    inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PN] d
    on d._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO
    where a._PROCESS_INST_NO='609390'
```

Comment: Did you check this query? `@@RowCount` will always be 1 here.

Comment: I checked it again normal join query. It will not always be 1. But I agree this is not a solution as if there is any query before this statement @@RowCount will return result of that query. If not, this should return fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

Give an alias to result set and get the `COUNT(*)` from that.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT
  a._PROCESS_INST_NO,
  a._ISSUER,
  a._ISSUE_DATE,
  d._PROCESS_CONTENTS,
  d._OPT_DIVISION,
  b._GOODS_CD,
  b._GOODS_NAME,
  b._QTY,
  a._Order_No,
  c._GOODS_CD,
  c._GOODS_NAME,
  a._NOTE,
  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a._PROCESS_INST_NO ORDER BY d._PROCESS_CONTENTS)) Proc_Step_No
--,() as Total_Rows
FROM [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PH] a
INNER JOIN [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PM] b
  ON b._PROCESS_INST_NO = a._PROCESS_INST_NO
INNER JOIN [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] c
  ON c._PROCESS_INST_NO = a._PROCESS_INST_NO
INNER JOIN [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PN] d
  ON d._PROCESS_INST_NO = a._PROCESS_INST_NO
WHERE a._PROCESS_INST_NO = '609390') AS tabl
```

If you want `COUNT(*)` along with resultset, you can use `CTE`. You need  SQL Server 2005 or higher version to do CTE

```
WITH tabl
AS (SELECT
  a._PROCESS_INST_NO,
  a._ISSUER,
  a._ISSUE_DATE,
  d._PROCESS_CONTENTS,
  d._OPT_DIVISION,
  b._GOODS_CD,
  b._GOODS_NAME,
  b._QTY,
  a._Order_No,
  c._GOODS_CD,
  c._GOODS_NAME,
  a._NOTE,
  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a._PROCESS_INST_NO ORDER BY d._PROCESS_CONTENTS)) Proc_Step_No
--,() as Total_Rows
FROM [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PH] a
INNER JOIN [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PM] b
  ON b._PROCESS_INST_NO = a._PROCESS_INST_NO
INNER JOIN [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] c
  ON c._PROCESS_INST_NO = a._PROCESS_INST_NO
INNER JOIN [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PN] d
  ON d._PROCESS_INST_NO = a._PROCESS_INST_NO
WHERE a._PROCESS_INST_NO = '609390')
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM tabl)
  total_count
FROM tabl
```

Comment: I think he wants all columns with number of rows returned as additional column and not only count.

Comment: @AB_87 Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Count will not work as Sankar says in comment... It will return 1. 
@@ROWCOUNT will work.

```
select a._PROCESS_INST_NO,a._ISSUER,a._ISSUE_DATE,d._PROCESS_CONTENTS, d._OPT_DIVISION,b._GOODS_CD,b._GOODS_NAME,b._QTY, a._Order_No,c._GOODS_CD,c._GOODS_NAME,a._NOTE, ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a._PROCESS_INST_NO ORDER BY d._PROCESS_CONTENTS) )Proc_Step_No ,@@ROWCOUNT as Total_Rows from [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PH] a inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PM] b on b._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PMS] c on c._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO inner join [ENVNDIVDB].[dbo].[TBL_PROC_PN] d on d._PROCESS_INST_NO=a._PROCESS_INST_NO where a._PROCESS_INST_NO='609390'
```

Comment: First, You have to know about `group by` and `count`. The `count(*)` will always return 1 in your query.